# Unable to start web site IIS HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, webserver

I'm trying to publish a web site with a self-created SSL certificate on my own IP. After I added the web site to the IIS and tried to run it, I get this error and I'm unable to start the web site.

> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

What can be the reason of that problem?

Comment: Check to see if Skype is running. Usually it takes over https port.

Comment: It happens sometimes, that WAS and W3SVC services hang permanently and the IIS Manager doesn't get control over inner site's 'restart' administrative option, so my suggestion is stop/start/restart the service in the Task Manager Services tab. It worked for me.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Check this   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015/en-us

Another process is using port 80 or port 443 on the computer that is running IIS. By default, IIS uses port 80 as the default TCP port and port 443 for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

Comment: This is 100% right, my issue was that Skype was running on port 443. I just configured Skype settings to use a different port.
I hope this helps some poor soul when they stumble upon this.

Comment: Yes, I was also facing the same issue due to Skype. to check it I closed Skype and error gone.

Comment: Had kind of assumed Skype stopped doing this, but nope - they still do - even in 2017...

Comment: @Ignacio - Thanks :)

Comment: In my case, vmware-host was the culprit. Setting can be found in "Shared VMs"

Answer (score 71):

To further elaborate Nacho's (correct) answer, from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973094):

Run the following command from a command prompt to find the PID of the process which is using TCP port 80 and/or 443 (hint: for 443, **it's probably Skype**):

```
netstat -aon | find ":80" 
netstat -aon | find ":443"
```

You will see an output similar to the following. Remember the actual PID will vary from case to case.

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3604 
TCP    0.0.0.0:443           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3320
```

Now using Task Manager you can easily find out to which process the above PID belongs and take appropriate action.

Comment: `Skype Options > Advanced > Connections`  Disable using 80 and 443 ports. This fixed the problem for me. Thanks

Comment: The best answer, due not always is Skype.

Comment: Nice answer though totally irrelevant, if my webservice uses 7777 and 7778 as respective ports

Comment: In my case it was "VMWare" hypervisor service. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For me, it was SoftEther listening on port 443 (it was installed after IIS so only grabbed that port when IIS was stopped / restarted). Easy solution to remove that port from SoftEther. NetStat gave me the PID, a quick Shift Ctrl Escape told me the process. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

In my case Skype was the culprit. Yes, you read it correctly: Skype was using port 80/443.

Below is the way to disable it-

1. launch Skype -> Tools -> Options
2. go to advance settings -> connection
3. uncheck the "use port 80 and 443 ...."

   [image]
4. save and quit your Skype or restart your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple IP addresses, are running dual stack (IPv4 and IPv6), and you try to create a HTTPS binding (443) for an IIS Website, it will attempt to listen on `0.0.0.0:443` and `[::]:443` regardless of what IP address you specify for the Site HTTPS Binding.

To override this behaviour, you will need to manually specify which IP and port to listen on in HTTP.sys (Example below assumes the IP address is `10.123.123.123`):

```
netsh http add iplisten 10.123.123.123:443
```